# How to reduce binary footprint when using Haskell package 'plugins'?

Tags: haskell, plugins, footprint

I have implemented a simple-minded loader for haskell plugins to my Main.hs module. The only function I use right now is `load` from [this site](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plugins/1.5.2.1/doc/html/System-Plugins-Load.html)

Looking at my compiled application size shows me an over 53 MB executable on the x86 architecture. I understand that big parts of GHC are linked in (due to the haskell-source-to-binary-plugin feature) but this is overkill for my purposes.

**Is there an officially sanctioned way to shave off the extra features and only keep `(dyn-)load`?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Small Haskell program compiled with GHC into huge binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115459/small-haskell-program-compiled-with-ghc-into-huge-binary)

Comment: @DanielWagner -- creating a `-dynamic` application would have still referenced the huge shared libraries, so the deployment issue would not have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the meaning of 'officially sanctioned'. `plugins` (formerly known as `hs-plugins`) was designed to be an all-encompassing solution, with code generation and dynamic loading features. It does not aim at minimality.

A less complex package is available under the name `direct-plugins`, which focuses on the dynamic loading of plugins. This package reads Haskell interface (`.hi`) files to obtain the actual types of symbols, so that type-safeness is possible, but an unsafe variant is also provided. Unfortunately `direct-plugins` is bitrotten and does not work (a.t.m.) with GHC v7.6.

At the lowest end of the spectrum there is the `unix` package which provides a `dlopen`/`dlsym`-like mechanism to get hold of symbols that are exported from shared libraries. A convenience layer is also provided to automatically close open libraries after processing with them has terminated. However the symbols are obtained as FFI `Ptr`s and are not Haskell-callable.

By searching the internet I discovered an abandoned package that seems to be operating at middle ground:

- loading of symbols with Haskell calling convention is provided
- dependencies and package/module hierarchy can be declared
- dependency environment is managed in a thread-safe way.

The original package is authored by Hampus Ram. I have only prepared it for the latest released GHC and did some very shallow testing. Here is the repository:

> https://github.com/ggreif/dynamic-loader

The only missing part is type-safe symbol access (by a possibly configurable mechanism).
Comments and patches welcome.

Comment: As of today all loading routines that return polymorphic results must be given an argument that is used to perform 'expectation checking' on the loaded symbol by some (open-ended) criteria.