# Could not find module Prelude... dyn libraries for package base?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Trying to follow the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115703/74865) proposed in the answer to [reducing haskell's binary question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115459/small-haskell-program-compiled-with-ghc-into-huge-binary), I keep getting the error, when I install with `--enable-shared` option:

```
> cabal install opengl --enable-shared --reinstall   
...
Could not find module `Prelude' 
Perhaps you haven't installed the "dyn" libraries for package `base'?
```

Tried everything. I'm using `apt-get installed`[`haskell-platform`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/haskell-platform) (with ghc 7.4.1), on Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit.

ANY tips?

Answer (score 10):

It seems that Ubuntu's Haskell platform doesn't include dynamic libraries.

You can try installing [ghc-dynamic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ghc-dynamic), that should work, I assume the distro packagers know what they're doing. You would probably need to install the *-dynamic packages for several libraries included in the platform too.

In case it doesn't work, the only suggestions I can make is to compile GHC yourself from source (using the installed GHC), or use a vanilla GHC bindist, those come with dynamic libraries, as far as I'm aware.

Both would require reinstalling (recompiling included) the libraries, though (perhaps best to compile the vanilla [platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/linux.html) from source then), so I recommend trying the distribution packages first.

Comment: Debian (and hence Ubuntu) currently only provides dynamic versions of the libraries that come with ghc, including `base`, install ghc-dynamic for that. All other libraries do not have dynamic versions yet. We decided against it, due to the high risk of ABI breakagae after an upgrade.