# Sharing SO's ( Shared Object ) between different Linux versions

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, centos, shared-libraries

I have build opencv which is a C++ Package in Ubuntu 12.04 and generated the "SO" files. Now I need to use these SO ( shared Object ) files in CENTOS ( which is another linux version ).

I copied the SO's generated in Ubuntu to Centos ( /usr/local/lib ). Will these libraries work in CENTOS?

I tried out and looks like its not working.. Still I am not sure whether the So will work or not. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

> I tried out and looks like its not working.. Still I am not sure whether the So will work or not.

If it's not working already, then why are you *not sure* whether it will work or not? You've experimentally **proved** that it doesn't.

Nor is it expected to.

What's likely happening (and you *should* mention this in your question) is that you get some `GLIBC_2.14` or some such symbol version that is not defined.

This is because your Ubuntu system has newer system libraries than your CentOS one.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617) for possible workarounds.