# Fixing libc.so.6 unexpected reloc type 0x25

Tags: shared-libraries, glibc, libc, suse, gcc4.9

I'm trying to install gcc4.9 on a SUSE system without an internet connection. I compiled gcc on an Ubuntu machine and installed it into a prefix, then copied the prefix folder to the SUSE machine. When I tried to run it gcc complained about not finding GLIBC_2_14, so I downloaded an rpm for libc6 online and included it into the prefix folders. my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes prefix/lib and prefix/lib64. When I try to run any program now (`ls`, `cp`, `cat`, etc) I get the error `error while loading shared libraries: /home/***/prefix/lib64/libc.so.6: unexpected reloc type 0x25`.

Is there any way I can fix this so that I can get gcc4.9 up and running on this system?

As an alternative, is it possible to build gcc staticaly so that I don't have to worry about linking at all when I transfer it between computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes prefix/lib and prefix/lib64

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) for explanation of why this can't work.

> Is there any way I can fix this so that I can get gcc4.9 up and running on this system?

Your best bet is to install whatever GCC package comes with the SuSE system, then use *that* GCC to configure and install gcc-4.9 on it.

If for some reason you can't do that, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617) has some of the ways in which you can build gcc-4.9 on a newer system and have it still work on an older one.

> is it possible to build gcc staticaly so that I don't have to worry about linking at all when I transfer it between computers?

Contrary to popular belief, fully-static binaries are generally *less* portable then dynamic ones on Linux.