# Linking with gmock libs generated using GCC 3.4.6 (libstdc++.so.6.0.13) gives "undefined reference to... @GLIBCXX_3.4.9" errors

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc, googlemock, libstdc++

Linking with gmock(1.4+svn281) libs generated on a Linux machine "A", having GCC 3.4.6 using **libstdc++.so.6.0.13** gives me the following linking error:

libgmock.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream >& std::__ostream_insert >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*, long)**@GLIBCXX_3.4.9**'
...

I tried also with the latest gmock release version and also got the undefined reference to... @GLIBCXX_3.4.9 errors (this time with other symbols).

Building gmock using the same build procedure, however on another machine "B" (retired machine now, but previously used to generate the older binaries) I was able to link successfully. The machine uses GCC 3.4.6, with a different libstdc++ version: **libstdc++.so.6.0.3**.

Grepping on libstdc++.so.6.0.13 for GLIBCXX_3.4.9 shows that it contains such symbol patterns:
_ZNSt13basic_ostreamIwSt1@@GLIBCXX_3.4.9 (referencing GLIBCXX_3.4.9, hence the error). I verified that this is not the case for libstdc++.so.6.0.3

- To understand the linking error and what are my options, I read about libstdc++ and glibcxx to get some perspective, but couldn't conclude the relation between the libs: Does libstdc++ need glibcxx or is it the other way around (the error message makes it seem that the problem is: at glibcxx there is an undefined reference to a symbol in libstdc++)?
- Does libstdc++ implicitly link with glibcxx (knowing that libstdc++ can reference multiple glibcxx versions at a time)?
- I don't want to go back to the old machine to build gmock whenever I want to update the libs, am I constrained to building gmock with specific libstdc++ versions that work?

Appreciate any help on the issue

EDIT:

I built gmock libs on machine "A" and specified the version of libstdc++: libstdc++.so.6.0.3 and got the same errors as before, but this time without the @GLIBCXX_3.4.9 appended at the end of the symbol:

libgmock.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream >& std::__ostream_insert >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*, long)'
...

I also verified that libstdc++.so.6.0.3 was actually taken, by launching the command: "readelf -a libgmock.so" and verifying that GLIBCXX_3.4.9 was not referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To understand the linking error and what are my options, I read about libstdc++ and glibcxx to get some perspective, but couldn't conclude the relation between the libs: Does libstdc++ need glibcxx

There is no such thing as `glibcxx` library. The `libstdc++.so` uses GNU symbol versioning, and uses `GLIBCXX` symbol prefix. The whole `GLIBCXX` is *implementation detail* of `libstdc++` itself.

Your actual problem, and possible solutions, is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617).

Effectively, you can not expect a binary linked on a newer Linux system to work on an older one.

Comment: As you mentioned about linking on a newer Linux system: I was using a newer g++ for building gmock (I verified gcc's version whereas I should have verified g++)