# ELF weak import / fallback stubs for glibc functions

Tags: linux, linker, glibc, elf, libc

I am trying to make our program runnable on some old Linux versions. One common import that prevents it is `__longjmp_chk`, added in glibc 2.11 but missing in older ones. One "solution" is to use `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` but this turns off other fortify functions (`__printf_chk` etc) which are present in the target libc. Is there a way to make `__longjmp_chk` a "weak import" which would use the function from `libc.so.6` if present, and fall back to local stub if not?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make `__longjmp_chk` a "weak import" which would use
>   the function from `libc.so.6` if present, and fall back to local stub
>   if not?

I'd say yes, using `dlsym()` to check for `__longjmp_chk` and acting accordingly:

```
/* cc -ldl */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void __longjmp_chk(sigjmp_buf env, int val)
{
    void (*p)(sigjmp_buf, int) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__longjmp_chk");
    if (p)
        printf("use the function from libc\n"),
        p(env, val);
    else
    {
        printf("falling back to local stub\n");
        /* local stub - whatever that may be */
    }
}

main()
{   // try it
    sigjmp_buf env;
    while (!setjmp(env)) __longjmp_chk(env, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make our program runnable on some old Linux versions.

There are only a few ways to make this work, and most of them are enumerated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617).

> Is there a way to make __longjmp_chk a "weak import".

No.