# How to strip symbol version information from the symbol dependency table of a shared library in Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, glibc, memcpy

I need a way to strip (or change, if stripping is not possible) the symbol version information from the symbol dependency table of a shared library in Linux, so I can work around the `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14` disaster, so I can make my binaries work on Linuxes with glibc older than 2.14 again.

Is there any tool for that?

Note: The `__asm__('.symver')` directive doesn't work for me because the problem is not that *my* library uses memcpy, but that my library uses something from libgcc and *that* uses memcpy@GLIBC_2.14, which is why I need a tool to change that *after* compilation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a way to strip (or change, if stripping is not possible) the symbol version information from the symbol dependency table of a shared library in Linux, so I can work around the `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14` disaster,

Stripping symbol version info

- is not possible without rebuilding a lot of internal ELF structures inside the linked binary (i.e. impossible in practice) and
- (even if you succeeded) will not produce a binary that will work on older GLIBC.

> so I can make my binaries work on Linuxes with glibc older than 2.14 again.

You can find approaches to "build on newer system, run on older one" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617).

Comment: "you can find approaches..." I saw them, they are beyond absurd for something as simple as this.