# Use RPATH to point to libc library

Tags: linux, linker, glibc, libc

I need to deploy my shared library (.so) in an ancient linux distro (CentOS 6.5).

The problem is that I'm actually compiling my code using CentOS 7 (gcc 4.8.2) and the libc versions are different.

My code depends on the GLIBC 2.14, however, the newest GLIBC version at CentOS 6.5 is 2.13.

I would like to use the *RPATH* mechanism and deploy the libc files along with the shared library file (.so).

Is this even possible?

## What I did so far

I've created a directory containing:

`$ ls
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  libc.so.6  libgcc_s.so.1  libm.so.6  libstdc++.so.6`

### -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++

These help with the problem of GLIBCXX.
However, the GLIBC version problem remains:

`` /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by sss_reactions/libsss_reactions.so) ``

### --rpath and --dynamic-linker

Using the `readelf` utility I saw that the RPATH was correctly set, and calling `ldd` on the library also points to the correct directory (containing the newer libc).

However, when I try to load the library with `dlopen()` I get the same error:

`` /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by sss_reactions/libsss_reactions.so) ``

### Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

In this case, I get this error:

`$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../dist/ ./Dlopen
./Dlopen: relocation error: ../dist/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference`

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use the RPATH mechanism and deploy the libc files along with the shared library file (.so).
>
> Is this even possible?

No, it's not, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) answer for what's involved in having multiple instances of `libc.so.6` coexist on a single host.