# “Version `GLIBC_2.16' not found” target host error after upgrading build environment to Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: build, glibc

After upgrading build environment to Ubuntu 14.4, main executable refuses to start on hosts with older Linux version with the following message:

> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found
>   (required by ./executable_name)

In order to safely distribute my package to hosts, which have older **Glibc**, should I try:

- linking statically against libc?
- downgrading libc on the build machine?
- install older glibc along with one Ubuntu distributive goes?
  with?

Note:
 - I don't need to use any binaries from older Ubuntu versions
 - I don't need to build on older Ubuntu version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying Yesod to Heroku, can't build statically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657908/deploying-yesod-to-heroku-cant-build-statically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After long investigation I finally found solution for the issue.

First of all I looked at the executable file dependencies:

```
ldd -v <executable_name>
```

My build is built with Cmake and only its Release version has the following dependency:

```
Version information: 
    ./build/Release/products/<executable_name>: 
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.16) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

On analyzing this file with objdump, I retrieved that it needs *__poll_chk* symbol:

```
00000000       F *UND*  00000000              __poll_chk@@GLIBC_2.16
```

Though Glibc uses so called *_symbol versioning _*, this particular function was added only in [Glibc 2.16](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=d9a216c037590c414e4069afde01fde84794e0d6).

Therefore I tried investigating what caused the difference between Debug and Release builds.

When [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=cmake_build_type) is set, Cmake defines domestic variables, which determine compiler flags. For GCC 4.8.4 they are:

- Debug: -g
- Release: -NDEBUG -O3

Glibc *poll.h* includes *poll2.h*, which contains tricky *_poll_chk* yet unavailable in GLibc 2.16. This include goes under *_USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL* define.

And according to Linux man pages (see quotes below) in Release build I have *-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2* due to *-O3* level.

```
man gcc
```

> NOTE: In Ubuntu 8.10 and later versions, -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 is set by
>   default, and is activated when -O is set to 2 or higher.   This
>   enables additional compile-time and run-time checks for several libc
>   functions.  To disable, specify either -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE or
>   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0.

```
man feature_test_macros
```

> _FORTIFY_SOURCE (since glibc 2.3.4) Defining this macro causes some lightweight checks to be performed to detect some buffer overflow
>   errors when employing various string and memory manipulation
>   functions.   Not all buffer overflows  are  detected, just  some 
>   common  cases.   In  the  current  implementation,  checks  are  added
>   for calls to memcpy(3), mempcpy(3), memmove(3), memset(3), stpcpy(3),
>   strcpy(3), strncpy(3), strcat(3), strncat(3), sprintf(3), snprintf(3),
>   vsprintf(3), vsnprintf(3), and gets(3).  If _FORTIFY_SOURCE is set to
>   1, with compiler optimization level 1 (gcc -O1) and above, checks that
>   shouldn't change the behavior of conforming programs  are performed. 
>   With _FORTIFY_SOURCE set to 2 some more  checking is added, but some
>   conforming programs might fail.  Some of the checks can be performed
>   at compile time, and result in compiler warnings; other checks take
>   place at run time, and result in a run-time error if the check fails. 
>   Use of this macro requires compiler support, available with gcc(1)
>   since version 4.0.

or just use

```
man -K _FORTIFY_SOURCE
```

I checked every static library my executable includes, whose code uses *poll* function and ultimately had found it:

```
objdump -t  lib.a | grep poll
00000000         *UND*  00000000 Curl_poll
00000000 l    d  .text.Curl_poll    00000000 .text.Curl_poll
00000000         *UND*  00000000 poll
00000000         *UND*  00000000 __poll_chk
00000000 g     F .text.Curl_poll    0000025c Curl_poll
```

This optimization may be disabled by adding *-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE* to the compiler flags within target CmakeLists.txt. This eliminate any lately detected GLIBC2.16 dependencies:

```
Version information:
products/<executable>:
    ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
    librt.so.1 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
    libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
    libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
    libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    libpulse.so.0 (PULSE_0) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0
    libsndfile.so.1 (libsndfile.so.1.0) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.15) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

The only thing I can't get is why I donn't have such problems in other static libraries which invokes GLibc poll as well?

To make the situation clear I used special GCC flag to display preprocessor output:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -E")
```

*.c.o* includes *poll.h* and *poll2.h* and its content goes as following:

```
# 1 "/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/poll2.h" 1 3 4 
# 24 "/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/poll2.h" 3 4 


extern int __poll_alias (struct pollfd *__fds, nfds_t __nfds, int __timeout) __asm__ ("" "poll") 
                               ; 
extern int __poll_chk (struct pollfd *__fds, nfds_t __nfds, int __timeout, 
         unsigned int __fdslen); 
extern int __poll_chk_warn (struct pollfd *__fds, nfds_t __nfds, int __timeout, unsigned int __fdslen) __asm__ ("" "__poll_chk") 


  __attribute__((__warning__ ("poll called with fds buffer too small file nfds entries"))); 

extern __inline __attribute__ ((__always_inline__)) __attribute__ ((__gnu_inline__)) __attribute__ ((__artificial__)) int 
poll (struct pollfd *__fds, nfds_t __nfds, int __timeout) 
{ 
  if (__builtin_object_size (__fds, 2 > 1) != (unsigned int) -1) 
    { 
      if (! __builtin_constant_p (__nfds)) 
 return __poll_chk (__fds, __nfds, __timeout, __builtin_object_size (__fds, 2 > 1)); 
      else if (__builtin_object_size (__fds, 2 > 1) / sizeof (*__fds) < __nfds) 
 return __poll_chk_warn (__fds, __nfds, __timeout, __builtin_object_size (__fds, 2 > 1)); 
    } 

  return __poll_alias (__fds, __nfds, __timeout); 
}
```

But library object file still has only upper *poll* symbol:

```
objdump -t  lib.a | grep poll 
00000000 UND    00000000 poll
```

So far I can't explain why tricky *__poll_chk* symbol is not added to the other libraries. But now my binary runs on any of target Linux hosts.