# glibc 2.14 not recognized by TensorFlow installation in Redhat

Tags: tensorflow, redhat, glibc

After TF complaining about lack of glibc_2.14, I installed glibc_2.14 in my home dir (I am using a supercomputing account,and I don't have root access) However, I still get this error when I try running TF. I have installed TF in anaconda using conda install. The system runs a Red Hat  OS.

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by users/ABCD1234/user123/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

I suspect this is due to the TF installation not searching for glibc_2.14 in the home dir, instead searching in /lib64 system folder. How can I make TF work using glibc?

Comment: EDIT: I did install glibc_2.14, and not 2.1 as mentioned in my question. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Then edit your question and not add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need GLIBC-2.14, *not* (ancient) GLIBC-2.1.

In addition, you need to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617) on how to make your TF program use the copy of GLIBC in your home directory.