# Unable to fix a glibc error while installing tensorflow

Tags: linux, tensorflow, glibc

I am trying to install tensorflow on a server without root privileges. I used

```
pip install --user tensorflow
```

which generates error

> ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found.

This problem has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932215/error-while-using-a-newer-version-of-glibc). As mentioned in the answer to the question in the link and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657908/deploying-yesod-to-heroku-cant-build-statically/8658468#8658468), adding the `glibc` path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can lead to further errors.

My server has a newer version of `glibc` in the directory `/somepath/lib/glibc-2.22/`. How do I set my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` properly?

I am not using anaconda as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657908/deploying-yesod-to-heroku-cant-build-statically/8658468#8658468). My packages are in `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Comment: Related, see [Undefined reference to mempcy@GLIBC_2.14 when compiling on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12286460/608639). It has the fix in the context of `memcpy` circa Glibc 2.13. otherwise, see [ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17'](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/177) in the TensorFlow issue tracker.

Comment: You found the answer that explains why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will not work and what to do instead, and yet you ask "How do I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?". Which part of "this wouldn't work" is confusing?