# How to update libc6 with Putty SSH?

Tags: python, glibc

Im trying to run Stockfish chess engine, but in the line that execute the binary give me this error:

Script:

```
import chess
import chess.uci
import chess.engine

fen = 'r2qkb1r/1p1bpp1p/p1n2p2/8/B1pP4/5N2/P1P2PPP/RN1QK2R w KQkq - 0 12'
board = chess.Board(fen)
handler = chess.uci.InfoHandler()

engine = chess.uci.popen_engine('/home/egqbe6ns/public_html/stockfish_10_x64')
```

Error:

```
/home/egqbe6ns/public_html/stockfish_10_x64: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/egqbe6ns/public_html/stockfish_10_x64)
/home/egqbe6ns/public_html/stockfish_10_x64: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/egqbe6ns/public_html/stockfish_10_x64)
```

Im in a shared server, other python script execute ok!

How can I update this libc6 with PUTTY SSH?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I update this libc6 with PUTTY SSH?

You *can't*.

Your `stockfish_10_x64` binary was built on a GLIBC-2.17 or later system, and will *only* run on a system with that version of GLIBC (or a later one).

The only (not completely true, see below) way to get this working is to update the GLIBC on the server, and if you don't have `root` on that server, you can't do that.

You would need to get a different build of `stockfish_10_x64`, or run on a different server.

P.S. You may be tempted to try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD` solutions, but they [will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940995/50617).

P.P.S. Using explicit loader invocation with a newer GLIBC might work. Something like this:

- install GLIBC-2.17 or later into `/home/egqbe6ns/libc`.
- invoke `stockfish_10_x64` like so:

  `/home/egqbe6ns/libc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path=/home/egqbe6ns/libc/lib64:/lib64 /home/egqbe6ns/public_html/stockfish_10_x64`