# C++ static linking then -bash: ../bin/executable: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, libcurl, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have this application that compiles no problem on dynamic linking. When I go to static linking, I try:

g++   -std=c++11 -static -o ../bin/executable executable.o obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o obj4.o  ../lib/gzstream/libgzstream.a   -lgsl -Wl,-Bstatic -lcurl -Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions  -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lrtmp -lssh  -lpsl -lnettle -lgnutls -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -llber -lldap -llber -lbrotlidec -lz  -lgslcblas -llzma -lbz2 -lz  -lpthread

then I call the executable:

```
../bin/executable
```

Then I get:

```
 -bash: ../bin/executable: No such file or directory
```

but it does exist, ls confirms it:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username guest ? 7108400 Feb 12 23:07 ../bin/executable
```

. ldd works also:

```
ldd ../bin/executable
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd432c7000)
libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f0dcc5a4000)
libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f0dcc583000)
librtmp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f0dcc563000)
libssh.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4 (0x00007f0dcc4f5000)
libpsl.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f0dcc4e2000)
libnettle.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007f0dcc4a8000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f0dcc2d0000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f0dcc283000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f0dcc272000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f0dcc21c000)
libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f0dcc20e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0dcc1f2000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f0dcc1c7000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f0dcc1b4000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0dcc191000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0dcbfaf000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0dcbe60000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0dcbc6e000)
libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f0dcbaea000)
libhogweed.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007f0dcbab3000)
libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f0dcba2f000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f0dcb758000)
/lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0dcc5eb000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f0dcb622000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f0dcb60c000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f0dcb52d000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f0dcb4fc000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f0dcb4f5000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f0dcb4e6000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f0dcb4ca000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f0dcb4ad000)
libgssapi.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007f0dcb466000)
libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f0dcb443000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0dcb428000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0dcb422000)
libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f0dcb416000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f0dcb40d000)
libheimntlm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007f0dcb401000)
libkrb5.so.26 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007f0dcb36e000)
libasn1.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007f0dcb2c8000)
libhcrypto.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007f0dcb290000)
libroken.so.18 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007f0dcb275000)
libwind.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007f0dcb24b000)
libheimbase.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007f0dcb239000)
libhx509.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007f0dcb1eb000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f0dcb0c2000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f0dcb087000)
```

Also, strace with -ff seems to print out the correct message from the executable:

```
strace -ff /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  ../bin/executable
```

This is the output of readelf:

```
readelf -h ../bin/executable
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF64
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x424c40
Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          7105840 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x0
Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         12
Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         40
Section header string table index: 39
```

Comment: How did you get that bash error? `g++` should not call bash.

Comment: my apologies, I forgot to write, that this occurs when I call the executable, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -lZ ..bin/executable`

Comment: Can you do `readelf -h ../bin/executable`? this error appears if the file is executable but cannot be executed due to e.g. different architecture.

Comment: @madreblu Seems alright to me, is it the same if you do dynamic? [relevant](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists), maybe try running `file ../bin/executable`, I guess the loader is just not happy about something.

Comment: `strace -ff /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` why ld? Have you tried strace without ld with just the binary? No-such-file-on-exec is usually some problem with the loader.

Comment: @Quimby for the dynamic, it executes fine and I get:
"ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=19c43ebc1d38726bc84f89bc1ca76a4457ae9c1f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped"

Comment: @teapot418 yes and I get:
"execve("../bin/executable", ["../bin/executable"], 0x7ffe0cfa36a0 /* 22 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
strace: exec: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++
"

which is weird because with -ff I get the help menu at least.

Comment: @madreblu Looks fine too, unfortunately, I do not know how to help you more without being able to test it on my machine, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++ static linking

You are *not* doing static linking (because on your command line, you override `-static` with `-Bdynamic`).

The error means that the executable is requesting an ELF interpreter which does not exist on your system. Running `readelf -Wl ../bin/executable` will show you *which* ELF interpreter that is. Look for lines like this:

```
  INTERP         0x000318 0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

The `ldd` output shows that the actual ELF interpreter in your binary is `/lib/ld64.so.1`, and the reason for that interpreter is *probably* that GCC got confused by `-static` (a GCC flag) and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` (a flag that is *not* visible to the GCC driver, but is passed directly to `ld`) mixture.

This is also why invoking the binary via *correct* ELF interpreter: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ../bin/executable` works -- in that case the interpreter inside the `executable` is ignored.

---

Since you are *not* actually doing a `-static` link, I suspect that removing `-static` will fix the problem.

If you do want a fully-static link, then you should drop all the `-Wl,...` flags you currently have, and also note that your binary will likely *not* run (at least not correctly) on any system other than the one it was linked on. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42616580/50617).

Comment: thanks a lot!! I got rid of the problem because the program used libcurl. however, it seems that there is static binary.

Comment: I managed to solved the problem somehow, I compiled the library I was using without libcurl and managed to get a static binary. thank you @Employed Russian  and @Quimby!