# How to link to an older version math library?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, glibc, libc

I'm about to release a library (.so) to my client.
However, my client's platform is a very old debian(9.1 released on 2017).
My libray only works with >= glibc-2.27.
I managed to run program by the following tricks

```
// copy libm-2.27.so from my computer to the old debian
ln -sf ./libm-2.27.so libm.so.6
gcc ./test.c -o ./test -lmylib -L ./ -lm
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` ./test
```

But my client don't accept this solution.
Is it possible to link to an older version of math library ?
For instance, the client gives me the math library and I link my library against it in my computer.

thanks!

Comment: Yes, that might work, but it's not very nice. If you do want to use the new version of libm you should statically link it instead.

Comment: But the best thing to do would be to build releases of your library for this customer on Debian 9.1 - e.g. set up a VM or Docker. There's a risk changing compiler or other parts of glib will cause problems though.

Comment: I have no luck on linking libm statically.  I got this   /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.a(e_atan2.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_dl_x86_cpu_features' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Is it possible to install a toolchain that match with that of debian 9 on my ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: Sorry, you're right about linking statically: I forgot you're building a library yourself. You can probably set up the existing Debian binaries in a chroot, or start with the GCC source and build a cross-compiler targeting the Debian libraries I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My libray only works with >= glibc-2.27.

Is it because you actually require functionality that was added to GLIBC-2.27, or because you system just happens to have that version installed and you don't know how to build for an older system?

From the comments, it appears that you don't actually *need* GLIBC-2.27.

In that case, the simplest solution is to install a VM with Debian 9.1 in it, and build you library inside that VM.

This has an added advantage that you can *test* your library before you ship it to your client, in the environment that matches that of the client.

If you do not want a VM, other solutions are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617).

> I managed to run program by the following tricks ... But my client don't accept this solution.

Your client is *smart* to reject that solution: it can not generally work, and running in such environment would expose your client to a multitude of potential undefined behaviors and crashes. To understand why this is so, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).