# How can I build a program to run on a system with older libc?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

I build the simplest program on current newest Fedora distribution (35):

```
$ cat test.c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}

$ cc test.c
```

The resulting a.out can't be run on an older system, because the glibc on fedora 35 is 2.34:

```
$ readelf --dyn-sym a.out

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 3 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34 (2)
     2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
```

For example, on Ubuntu 20 I get this error:

```
$ ./a.out
./a.out: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

How can I build an program on newer Linux that can run on older Linux?

I couldn't find any simple solution.  There's [a complicated one](https://www.lightofdawn.org/wiki/wiki.cgi/NewAppsOnOldGlibc) but nothing simple.

Comment: Usually, the easiest way is to build in a Docker (or other) container containing your target platform, so that you link against the older library.  Or link statically - but that has trade-offs of its own.

Comment: Is there any link option to use old version function on glibc or totally disable symbol version

Comment: Unless you have old headers installed the compiler doesn't know what symbols the old glibc provides, or what their signatures are.

Comment: By the way, note that there **are** plenty of practical options -- be it installing those old headers, or running a completely static build (with the libc functions the executable needs built into the executable itself instead of loaded from a library). So anything equivalent to "you can't" is not an accurate answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Note that _headers_ have very little to do with symbol versioning -- you also need old library _binaries_ (`ctr0.o`, `libc.so.6`, etc.) to link against.

Comment: Dynamic linking happens at runtime. If you don't have symbol versions, for C, the headers are enough for dynamic content. (Your .o files _aren't_ dynamic content, granted, but that's why I'm narrowing my definitions; as long as the statically linked .o or .a files don't make version-specific assumptions about the dynamically linked content it's moot).

Comment: Anyhow -- in C, the headers determine the calling signature, and the ABI locks a signature down to a stack layout used to pass arguments during a call. So the headers have _everything_ to do with it; if you know the headers and the ABI spec the dynamic linker can put together the other details later.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your understanding of this issue appears to be incomplete. If your `.o` doesn't specify a version and you link that `.o` into `foo.so` without any version info present, your `foo.so` will be "versionless". Which (of the several available) version do you think will be selected _at runtime_? Answer: the _wrong_ one.

Comment: As I understand the premise and goal, the intent is to build a binary to be deployed to a system with only an old version, so behavior on systems with multiple choices of libc is moot. Which is to say, yes, I know what symbol versions are for. That doesn't mean they're always relevant or necessary.

Comment: (Hi; I used to be half the team doing userland porting and packaging for an embedded distro back around 2000 or so. That's a world where one very much cares only about making the contents of an image mutually compatible with everything else in that same image; one thing we wrote tools for was to strip any symbols the customer's installed binaries never linked to out of the local shared libraries).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I build an program on newer Linux that can run on older Linux?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617) (down at the bottom) for possible solutions.

> Is there any link option to use old version function on glibc or totally disable symbol version

The symbol versioning is there *for a reason* -- the symbols are not ABI-compatible. If there was a link option to disable symbol versioning, your executable built with it would then run on the older system, and *crash* with an error that would be very hard for you to understand.

Comment: If a question can be fully answered by a link to a different question's answers, why not just mark it as duplicate?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Because the question is _not at all_ a duplicate.

Comment: ... Which is why a new and different answer should be written. (You've already started making some headway towards that end).