# Statically include libc in c++ program with gcc without using -static option

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, dynamic-linking

I am trying to build a small c++ program with the least amount of dynamic dependencies as possible.
The problem i am facing is that the program I am trying to build has a dynamic dependency with libmariadbcpp (which cannot be statically linked).

I.e. using **-static** option in compile command cause the compilation to fail, with error

> /usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/local/lib/../lib/libmariadbcpp.so'

Currently the program builds by using the command

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -lmariadbcpp
```

But running ldd on main shows dependencies with libc.so.6, libm.so.6 and others...

Obviously the command

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -lmariadbcpp -static
```

does not work because **-static** overrides **-lmariadbcpp** but "logically" resemble what i would like to achieve.

I tried using **-static-libstdc++** but there was no visible effect on produced binary (libc and libm were still listed by ldd).

Is there a way for me to statically compile my program such that no dynamic dependencies are listed by ldd except for libmariadbcpp?

**Bonus question**: where are options such as -static-libstdc++ defined? I tried looking for them by using --help with gcc and ld but to no avail.

Thank you very much!

*Some additional info*:

The issue i was trying to solve in a more broader sense is that the servers on which i work each has a different os distribution/version, and code compiled on my computer with dynamic dependencies fails to execute remotely (with errors such as `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.34 not found`).

Currently i am either re-compiling the programs on each server or wrapping them in docker containers, but this is not very practical so i thought removing dynamic dependencies was the way to go.

Comment: It's unlikely to work, as `libc` and `libm` are most likely linked by `libmariadbcpp.so` itself, which is why they still appear as part of the dependencies of the application when you link against the library.

Comment: Static linking considered harmful. If you need to bundle up your dependencies for an easily distributable build, use rpath (the only caveat is: *if* you have a setuid or similarly privileged program, relative or world-writable rpaths should be avoided. Other arguments against rpath are FUD), though it's best just to build on the oldest system supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to statically compile my program such that no dynamic dependencies are listed by ldd except for libmariadbcpp?

No.

If you are using *any* shared library *at all*, then you *must* also use `ld-linux.so` and `libc.so`.

In fact, running `ldd /usr/local/lib/libmariadbcpp.so` will show both `libc.so.6` and `ld-linux`, so your `main` will always have these dependencies no matter what.

> Bonus question: where are options such as -static-libstdc++ defined?

In the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

P.S. http://xyproblem.info may be relevant here.

Comment: You are right the dependencies of libmariadbcpp.so negate what i am trying to do.
Removing dynamic dependencies is what i thought was needed to avoid re-compiling binaries on multiple servers.
Thank  you for your insight.

Comment: @DarkPangloss666 recompiling binaries on multiple servers should _not_ be necessary. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617