# Reduce the size of the Snap binary?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

When I compile my [Snap](http://snapframework.com/) webapp (to deploy it to production server), it comes out to 19MB!
What gives? Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong?

My site only has 3 static pages, basically [snap's init project](http://snapframework.com/docs/quickstart).

Comment: Is this somehow a problem?  Would using shared libraries make you feel better?

Comment: Well, I have to upload 20MB over slow `scp` connection to my EC2 instance every time I want to make a tiny change...

Comment: So it sounds like you should use shared Libraries to cut out the duplication.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Could you expand that into an answer please?

Comment: [Making small haskell executables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699908/making-small-haskell-executables)

Comment: Or you could compress the executable with `xz` before the transfer and decompress it afterwards... or in one pass with `xz -c9 a.out | ssh -v  ec2-host.amazon.com "xz -cd > a.out"`. That reduces a simple hello world app from 16MB to 1.6MB on my box.

Comment: @hal Thanks, but those answers are quite OLD!

Comment: @drozzy The answers in [the question linked by hal's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115459/small-haskell-program-compiled-with-ghc-into-huge-binary) aren't.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Snap pulls a lot of dependencies. One solution to this problem, which unfortunately affects the (initial) compilation time is to install **libraries your project depend on** with --split-objs option. That will generate a ton of different object but will make the final executable a lot smaller, like 2-4 times smaller.

```
$ cabal install --enable-split-objs
```

If you already have the libraries installed you will need to remove them first, install a fresh GHC or use sandbox with it's own package set.

You should also use `strip` command (cabal does this automatically in some cases).

Additionally you may consider using `upx` for compressing executables and finally `rsync` to upload minimally different executable to the server.

Using shared libraries (`cabal install --enable-shared`) may or may not help here: I didn't experiment with that option.

Comment: Should I do this both on the local server and on the production? Or just ensuring that production has Haskell is sufficient?

Comment: I tried both `--enable-split-objs` and `--enabled-shared` on my snap project and neither one seems to work. The binary is exactly the same size.

Comment: @drozzy You need to build the libraries that your project depend on with these options. Just recompiling your project won't do much. I would recommend starting with a clean installation of GHC for this purpose or using sandboxing solution for this (like virthualenv or something).

Comment: Thanks, do I then need to install GHC and all the dependencies on my production server? Have you ever used something like [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/)?